# Adapter is working wrong on this library

Tags: android, adapter, onclicklistener

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/alexvasilkov/FoldableLayout) to do an app which lists need to have that folding aspect. But each view (each element on that list) has 6 buttons and I can't add a `clickListener` to each button from adapter because it overrides with the `clickListener` of the last position. I used [another library](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip) but it works with OpenGL and it's a little bit buggy.

How can I do to set to each button an specific function?

I already set the `OnClickListener` in the adapter but it doesn't work:

```
public class CardQueryAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private int cant;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Cards> data;
DataBaseConnectionManager mDataBase;
int[] buttons=new int[]{R.id.button1,R.id.button2,R.id.button3,
        R.id.button4,R.id.button5,R.id.button6};

public CardQueryAdapter(Context context, DataBaseConnectionManager mDataBase) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mDataBase = mDataBase;
    data = mDataBase.getUserCards();
    cant = data.size();
    System.out.println("Size= "+cant+" "+(int) Math.ceil(cant/6.0));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mViewHolder = null;
    System.out.println("position: "+position);
    
    if (convertView == null) {
        
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_card_query, parent, false);
        
        mViewHolder.buttons[0] = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mViewHolder.buttons[1] = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mViewHolder.buttons[2] = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        mViewHolder.buttons[3] = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        mViewHolder.buttons[4] = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
        mViewHolder.buttons[5] = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button6);
        
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        
    }else{
        
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        
    }
    
    int j;
    if(cant<=6) j=cant;
    else if(getCount()-1!=position)j=6*position+6;
        else j=cant;
    
    System.out.println("Caso: "+6*position+" "+j);
    for(int i=6*position;i<j;i++){
        System.out.println("Bank: "+data.get(i).mID+" "+data.get(i).mDicName);
        mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        if(data.get(i).mDicName.equals("Mercantil")) {
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bank_mercantil);
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setText(data.get(i).mName);
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            //button.setHint(Integer.toString(data.get(i).mID));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setHint(Integer.toString(i));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(inflater.getContext(), Advertisement.class);
                    //i.putExtra("id", ((Button) v).getHint().toString());
                    i.putExtra("id", Integer.toString(data.get(Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getHint().toString())).mID));
                    i.putExtra("name", data.get(Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getHint().toString())).mName);
                    i.putExtra("bank", BanksInfo.MERCANTIL);
                    inflater.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }
                
            });
        }
        if(data.get(i).mDicName.equals("Venezuela")) {
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bank_venezuela);
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setText(data.get(i).mName);
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            //button.setHint(Integer.toString(data.get(i).mID));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setHint(Integer.toString(i));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(inflater.getContext(), Advertisement.class);
                    //i.putExtra("id", ((Button) v).getHint().toString());
                    i.putExtra("id", Integer.toString(data.get(Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getHint().toString())).mID));
                    i.putExtra("name", data.get(Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getHint().toString())).mName);
                    i.putExtra("bank", BanksInfo.VENEZUELA);
                    inflater.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }
                
            });
        }
        if(data.get(i).mDicName.equals("Provincial")) {
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bank_bbva);
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setTextColor(convertView.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setText(data.get(i).mName);
            //button.setHint(Integer.toString(data.get(i).mID));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setHint(Integer.toString(i));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(inflater.getContext(), Advertisement.class);
                    //i.putExtra("id", ((Button) v).getHint().toString());
                    i.putExtra("id", Integer.toString(data.get(Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getHint().toString())).mID));
                    i.putExtra("name", data.get(Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getHint().toString())).mName);
                    i.putExtra("bank", BanksInfo.BBVA);
                    inflater.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }
                
            });
        }
        if(data.get(i).mDicName.equals("Commerce")) {
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bank_commerce);
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setTextColor(convertView.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setText(data.get(i).mName);
            //button.setHint(Integer.toString(data.get(i).mID));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setHint(Integer.toString(i));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(inflater.getContext(), Advertisement.class);
                    //i.putExtra("id", ((Button) v).getHint().toString());
                    i.putExtra("id", Integer.toString(data.get(Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getHint().toString())).mID));
                    i.putExtra("name", data.get(Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getHint().toString())).mName);
                    i.putExtra("bank", BanksInfo.COMMERCE);
                    inflater.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }
                
            });
        }
    }
    
    if(getCount()-1==position)
        if(cant%6!=0){
            for(int i=(cant%6);i<6;i++){
                mViewHolder.buttons[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.extra);
                mViewHolder.buttons[i].setText("");
                mViewHolder.buttons[i].setHint("");
                mViewHolder.buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (int) Math.ceil(cant/6.0);
}

public void setCount(int cant) {
    this.cant = cant;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    private Button[] buttons = new Button[6];
}

}
```

In the following images you can see how it looks in the first and second position, but the button 7 is replacing the button 1 clickListener:

[image: How looks the first position]

[image: How looks the second position]

---

#### Solved

[The library](https://github.com/alexvasilkov/FoldableLayout) was updated and it had an issue. Now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that the 7th button overrides the 1st one lies in the logic you have written. I doubt its in this piece of code

```
int j;
if(cant<=6) j=cant;
else if(getCount()-1!=position)j=6*position+6;
    else j=cant;

System.out.println("Caso: "+6*position+" "+j);
for(int i=6*position;i<j;i++){
    System.out.println("Bank: "+data.get(i).mID+" "+data.get(i).mDicName);
```

**What you can do?**
  Put `log.d` generously in the code and see if the log prints as it should. Based on the log you can check which button is binding the call. print `i` inside the `for loop` and check each time which button is it selecting.